# Showing a folder content in document library

Tags: folder, content-and-structure

In my Sharepoint page I am trying to show a spesific folder named Animals.

My folder structuer is something like this:

> Pictures/Animals/Cats/
>
> Pictures/Animals/Dogs/
>
> Pictures/Animals/document.docx

And I have many subfolders in /Cats/ and /Dogs/. So i want to just show the content of the folder /Animals/. Not every subfolder under /Dogs/ and so on, just what is in the folder /Animals/.
How can I do this?

**EDIT 01.04**
To explain better I found this picture:
[image: Foldersystem]

Here I want to show one folder. Lets say "texts". Then the page should show the files and folders in "texts": bla[folder],foo.html and text.txt.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the view. On the filter section you have to select "Show items only when the following is true:". There you put in Content type is not equal to folder. Doing so will only show you the items in the root that are not folders.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.
I do want to show both folders and documents in the folder "Animals". But as it is now, I also show all the subfolders "Animals/Cats/BlackCats" and so on. I just want to show the one folder with all its content, documents and folders.

Comment: If you don't want to show subfolders you have to go to your view. In the folder section you select "show items inside folders" instead of "show all items without folders".

Comment: Well. Then I am doing something wrong. Because I added the Document Library. sites/MySite/Documents/Pictures/Animals/[Every animal]/.
And when i add the Web Part Documents. It shows instead the content of "Documents". So I can only see Pictures. But I want to show the folder Animals, so that people can choose a animal, and then go to the next folder. (I have to add that in the folder "Animals", it is also word-files and so on, and I want to see both folder and word-files under Animals. But none of the folder under Cats or Dogs or any else.) Just the files and folder in Animals-folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do anyone know the answer? I cant understand if I am the only one who have tried to show the content of a chosen folder?